# How to read 2’s complement value from two registers into an int

Tags: c, cpu-registers, twos-complement

I am trying to read values from the STC3100 battery monitor IC, but the values I am getting are not correct. What the datasheet says:

```
The temperature value is coded in 2’s complement format, and the LSB value is 0.125° C.

REG_TEMPERATURE_LOW, address 10, temperature value, bits 0-7
REG_TEMPERATURE_HIGH, address 11, temperature value, bits 8-15
```

This is the datasheet: http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/DATASHEET/CD00219947.pdf

What I have in my code:

```
__u8 regaddr = 0x0a; /* Device register to access */
__s32 res_l, res_h;

int temp_value;
float temperature;

res_l = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(myfile, regaddr);
regaddr++;
res_h = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(myfile, regaddr);
if (res_l < 0) {
  /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
} else {
  temp_value = (res_h << 8)+res_l;
  temperature = (float)temp_value * 0.125;
  printf("Temperature: %4.2f C\n", temperature);
}
```

What am I doing wrong? Is this not how I should copy a 2's complement value into an int?

Comment: Can you print the individual bytes reg_l and reg_h to make sure they're coming up as expected ?

Comment: Can you explain how the values you're getting are not correct?  What are you getting (the values of the register reads, `res_l` and `res_h`) and what do you expect?

Comment: damn. deleting my stupid comment. definitely a good idea to print res_l and res_h separately to see what they are.

Comment: @AlanCurry no worries :)

Comment: Also, keep in mind the following information from the datasheet: "Values held in consecutive registers (such as the charge value in the REG_CHARGE_LOW and REG_CHARGE_HIGH registers) must be read with a single I2C access to ensure data integrity". It's not the problem you're running into right now, but can cause intermittent wildly incorrect readings when the temperature is at certain boundary values (like around 0 or 32 degrees Celcius). This may be a bigger problem for reading other multi-register values.

Comment: @Michael: and how would I read the two registers with a single access?

Comment: @Reto: I'm sorry - I misread the code in the question.  You're already reading both registers with a single access. However, you're reading an additional two registers with the second call to `i2c_smbus_read_word_data()`. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` will read 16 bits starting from your specified register on the device, so a single `i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` will read both registers that you're interested in using a single i2c transaction.

`i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` returns the 16 bits read from the device as an unsigned quantity - if there's an error, the return from `i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` will be negative.  You should be able to read the temperature sensor like so:

```
__u8 regaddr = 0x0a; /* Device register to access */
__s32 res;

int temp_value;
float temperature;

res = i2c_smbus_read_word_data(myfile, regaddr);

if (res < 0) {
  /* ERROR HANDLING: i2c transaction failed */
} else {
  temp_value = (__s16) res;
  temperature = (float)temp_value * 0.125;
  printf("Temperature: %4.2f C\n", temperature);
}
```

To address questions from the comments:

The `i2c_smbus_read_word_data()` function returns the 16 bits of data obtained from the i2c bus as an unsigned 16-bit value if there's no error. A 16-bit unsigned value can easily be represented in the 32-bit int returned by the function, so by definition the 16-bits of data cannot be negative. `res` will be negative if and only if there's an error.

Interpreting the 16 bit value as a (possibly negative) two's complement value is handled by the `(__s16)` cast of `res`. This takes that value that's in `res` and converts it to a signed 16-bit `int` representation. Strictly speaking, it's implementation-defined regarding how negative numbers will be dealt with by this cast. I believe that on Linux implementations, this will always simply treat the lower 16 bits of `res` as a two's complement number.

If you're concerned about the implementation defined aspect of the `(__s16)` cast, you can avoid it by using arithmetic instead of a cast as in caf's answer:

```
temp_value = (res > 0x7fff) ? res - (0xffff + 1) : res;
```

Which will perform the correct conversion to a negative value even if you happen to be running on a one's complement machine (does Linux even support running on such a thing?).

Also note that the above posted code assumes you're running on a little-endian machine - you'll need to swap the bytes appropriately on a big-endian machine before converting the data to a negative value, The following should do the trick however the target CPU represents integer values (big/little, one' or two's):

```
__u16 data = __le16_to_cpu( (__u16) res);

// convert negative two's complement values to native negative value:
int temp_value = (data > 0x7fff) ? data - (0xffff + 1) : data;
```

Comment: Wow, this works great and the solution was so easy! I will mark this as the correct answer after this last question: what happens if the value is negative? Remember, these values can be negative and are stored in `2’s complement format`. So will my error handling fail? Will the negative values appear in my error handling or how should I treat negative values?

Comment: @Reto: I've updated the answer to try to address those questions directly.

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear from your post what the data type of i2c_smbus_read_word_data is, but if it's possible to return negative values, it can't be just unsigned bytes.  I would use res_l & 0xff
and res_h & 0xff just as an exercise in paranoia, since they are not supposed to contain anything of interest.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, if `int` happens to be a 32bit type, the expression  `temp_value = (res_h << 8) + res_l;` does not generate the correct result for negative values because the concatenation is 16 bit and the sign bit does not extend.

You should probably avoid any implicit conversions and specify precisely what you want to happen.  Implicit conversion rules and conversion between signed and unsigned are arcane and can produce unexpected results.  Splitting the expression up into smaller parts will also aid debugging as you will be able to see exactly which type conversion or bit-wise operation is incorrect.

I would also suggest consistency in arithmetic and bitwise operations preferring either `(a << 8) | b` or `(a * 256) + b` rather than `(a << 8) + b` as you have.

```
  __u8 tlow = (__u8)(res_l & 0xff) ;
  __u8 thigh = (__u8)(res_h & 0xff) << 8 ;
  __s16 temp_value = (__s16)((thigh << 8) | tlow);

  temperature = (float)temp_value * 0.125f ;
  printf("Temperature: %4.2hf C\n", temperature);
```

It is not entirely necessary to be that explicit with the masking and casting or to break it down as I have with additional variables, but it does avoid having to know the intricate details of implicit conversions that occur in mixed type expressions, and makes it very clear to the reader and the compiler what you intend to happen.  It also makes it simpler to debug since you can watch those intermediate values in your debugger (you use a debugger right!?).

If you do prefer terse then your original code can be corrected simply by making `temp_value` a `__s16` or by casting the expression to `__s16`, but since this has already tripped you up, I would not recommend it, it may also trip up the guy who later has to maintain or reuse this code.  Nontheless either of the following will work:

```
__s16 temp_value = (res_h << 8) | res_l ;
```

or

```
int temp_value = (__s16)((res_h << 8) | res_l);
```

The last one at least has the result in an `int`, which is both what you asked for and probably safer in terms of any subsequent arithmetic operations to be performed.

If you want to show that you really intended to cast to `__s16` then assign to an `int`, then make it explicit:

```
int temp_value = (int)((__s16)((res_h << 8) | res_l));
```

because some hapless maintainer may later think it is an error and attempt to "correct" it!

Answer (score 1):

You need to correctly handle the high bit.  The easiest way to do this is:

```
s32 temp_value = (res_h << 8) | res_l;
if (temp_value > 32767)
    temp_value -= 65536;
```

Don't forget to check if the `res_h` transaction failed, too.

Comment: I'd beg to differ with respect to "easiest". In the question the requirement is to assign to an `int`, but you have changed this to `s32`, which is not necessarily the same thing.  As it happens your code would work without the change of type even if `int` were 16 bit, but the test would in that case be redundant (i.e. always false), so if you are going to change the type why not use `__s16` and omit the test altogether?  Assigning an `__s16` to an `int` of any size has well defined and correct results with or without an explicit cast.

Comment: @Clifford: If `int` were 16 bit then the assignment of `res_h << 8 | res_l` would technically give an implementation-defined result if the highest bit of `res_h` were set.  It's clear from the code that the `temp_value` variable is a temporary intermediate before conversion to `float`.

Comment: It is indeed implementation defined, but not in the sense of the bit pattern, only in its interpretation.  It is a valid point and your code *is* portable to non-2's complement architectures, but I don't see many of them around! ;-). I took `temp_value` to mean "temperature value" rather than "temporary value" which seemed reasonable in context.  I assumed the conversion to float was merely for the purposes of displaying debug text.  Using "temp" to mean temporary in a variable name is always a bad idea, in temperature sensor code doubly so!

Comment: @Clifford: Assigning an out-of-range value to a signed integer type doesn't necessarily preserve any part of the bit pattern (and it's even allowed to raise an "implentation-defined signal"!) - saturating signed types for example are legal.

Comment: Conceded.  Perhaps "safest" rather than "easiest" would be a better description.